# Is there an online Python interpreter with the Pygame module?

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering if there is an online python interpreter with Pygame. It would be great if there is one, because when I share a game, I don't have to compile it first, I just send the code, and possibly upload the textures to a storage server and change the URL for the image location.

Is there an online Python interpreter with Pygame?

Comment: That would require a port of PyGame from SDL and some handwritten C to whatever web technology can replace it. Sounds pretty impractical, though I'm not ruling it out.

Comment: Looks like the answer is yes, such an interpreter exists in 2019. Try [repl.it](https://repl.it/site/blog/gfx?ref=updates)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None that I'm aware of. Running a Pygame application in the browser would require some way of displaying graphics and playing sound from a remote Python interpreter. This would be pretty complicated to do, and would likely not perform very well anyway.

If you want to write games which run in a web browser, learn Javascript.